# Making Bridge to Call WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, scripting-bridge

Here is my Scenario,

In my Server Project I have some WCF calls which uses oracle queries execution. VPN utility is installed on the machine to route these queries to particular server. Now problem is i cant have more than 1 instance of VPN and i need the same project to be installed on another machine to use same VPN. What i want is to have this VPN installed on one machine and any project can use it on different machine either on same or different network.

Do i need to make some kind of bridge on Server hosting VPN? which is used by any project? when i say bridge it might mean the WCF interface which gets the call and return the result to project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle Listener can be configured to proxy connections to another listener. You can install and configure a listener on the single machine with the VPN to connect to a remote listener (the actual Oracle server across the VPN). Then point the WCF servers' connection strings to the proxy listener server, and it will act as an Oracle server to the WCF code.

Comment: Can you please refer me some links how to install and configure Oracle Listener?